# How to access Scoreboard with one click

Tags: ps4, battlefield-1

When I play in multiplayer mode, I use to view the ScoreBoard continuously to see how well I'm performing.

[image]

It's easy to me in Star Wars Battlefront because I just need to click the touchpad (I'm playing in PS4).

But in Battlefield that's not possible even the game it's also from DICE. I need to click options and the move to ScoreBoard, and that is a big waste of time when you are playing. I get killed a lot of time as I'm viewing the Scoreboard.

Is there a way to watch the scoreboard instantly without stopping the game? It must be, it is supposed to be a competitive game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a quick way, all you have to do is **hold the options button**. As long as you hold it the scoreboard will be shown. This works for both PS4 and Xbox One.

Comment: great, this is going to improve my game since I don't have to loose time moving to the scoreboard manually.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP was about PS4 scoreboard key, but that is not evident in the question title.  So, for Windows users, the Tab key shows the scoreboard.